# Functions taking the same memory for local pointer initialization?

Tags: c, pointers, scope

In the following example from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-static-variables-functions/)

```
#include<stdio.h>

char** func1_Str();
char** func2_Str();

int main(void)
{
    char **ptr1 = NULL;
    char **ptr2 = NULL;

    ptr1 = func1_Str();
    printf("\n [%s] :: func1_Str() address = [%p], its returned address is [%p]\n",*ptr1,(void*)func1_Str,(void*)ptr1);

    ptr2 = func2_Str();
    printf("\n [%s] :: func2_Str()address = [%p], its returned address is [%p]\n",*ptr2,(void*)func2_Str,(void*)ptr2);

    printf("\n [%s] [%p]\n",*ptr1,(void*)ptr1);

    return 0;
}

char** func1_Str()
{
    char *p = "Linux";
    return &p;
}

char** func2_Str()
{
    char *p = "Windows";
    return &p;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./static 

 [Linux] :: func1_Str() address = [0x4005d5], its returned address is [0x7fff705e9378]

 [Windows] :: func2_Str()address = [0x4005e7], its returned address is [0x7fff705e9378]

 [Windows] [0x7fff705e9378]
$
```

Why would `func1_Str()` and `func2_Str()` use the same address for initializing `char *p`? Does it have something to do with the fact that the pointers are named equally?

Comment: Please don't make us read external projects. Post the relevant code here.

Comment: @self I have, it's just a reference to the original code. Are you suggesting i delete the link?

Comment: Questions should be self contained. You can edit it.

Comment: @self. Please suggest an edit. The question is standalone even if the link is removed.

Comment: Although I have written an answer, I fail to see why you are asking this - the site you linked to is explaining just why this happens - in fact, it's exactly THE POINT of the site you linked to. What is it you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable some warnings for your code, a good compiler will warn you that you are "returning the address of a local variable" (or something like that).

```
char** func1_Str()
{
    char *p = "Linux";
    return &p;
}
```

In this example, `p` is located on the stack, and initialized with the address of the constant string `"Linux"`. You are then returning the address of `p` on the stack, and immediately after that, the stack pointer is reset when the function returns to the caller. When you then call `func2_Str`, the same location on the stack is then reused `p`
 in `func2_Str`. The stack is like a stack of plates in a kitchen, you put new ones on when you call into a function, you take the off again when returning.

So, yes, you'll get the same address for both of your pointers, and because of that, anything they point to will be the same as well, of course.

The name of the variable has nothing to do with it (as you would have found out if you tried the simple experiment of renaming one of them to something else). You could also do something like this:

```
char** func1_Str()
{
    char *q = "Windows";
    char *p = "Linux";
    return &p;
}
```

And you'd (probably) see that `p`'s value has changed, because we now need another four bytes.

(I also find it rather amazing that your system gets EXACTLY the same address as the example in the link - are you actually compiling this yourself, or just copying and pasting from the site)
(Of course, if you had actually read the text on the site you linked, you would have understood that)

Comment: What i didn't understand was the the functions having the same stacks. That was addressed in the comments of the article and no answers were given. The examples you provide explain why the stacks are the same. The example is completely from the project because it was the concept i couldn't understand. Why would it be different if the addresses were not the same?

Comment: Ok, so "stack" - not "stacks" - as long as we're talking about a single-threaded application, there is only one stack. Everything builds up on the stack when you call functions, and when you return, the stack content goes back down.

Answer (score 1):

It so happens that that the stack memory requirements for `func1_Str` and `func2_Str` are exactly the same. As a result, the memory location used for `p` in `func1_Str` happened to coincide with the memory location used for `p` in `func2_Str`.